# CustomLabels- " Error parsing file: Unexpected element {http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata}ol during simple type deserialization"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud, salesforce-lightning

Error parsing file:-

```
Unexpected element {http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata} 
ol during simple type deserialization


"<ol>"  // Syntax  
"<li>"  // Syntax
```

Comment: <li> -- Syntax & <ol> for custom label value

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you've got some HTML in your xml file that you've sent to Salesforce.

Have you got full request?